# Email link on button click

Tags: vb.net, function

I have a function to send an email, however I am unable to call it in a sub on the same form.

```
Imports System.Net.Mail

Public Function SendEmail(EmailBody As String, 
                  EmailSubject As String, EmailTo As String, 
                  AttachmentPath As String, EmailAsHTML As Boolean)

    Dim Mail As New MailMessage

    Try
        Dim SMTP As New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com")
        SMTP.EnableSsl = True
        SMTP.Credentials = New System.Net.NetworkCredential("[your gmail address@gmail.com]", "[the associated password]")
        SMTP.Port = 587

        Mail.From = New MailAddress("""[Friendly Name]"" <[your gmail address@gmail.com>")

        'Split Multiple Addresses
        If EmailTo.Contains(";") Then
            For Each EmailAddress In EmailTo.Split(";")
                Mail.To.Add(Trim(EmailAddress))
            Next
        Else
            Mail.To.Add(Trim(EmailTo))
        End If

        Mail.Subject = EmailSubject
        Mail.Body = EmailBody
        If AttachmentPath <> "" Then Mail.Attachments.Add(New Mail.Attachment(AttachmentPath))
        Mail.IsBodyHtml = EmailAsHTML

        SMTP.Send(Mail)

        'Clear Mail Object
        Mail.Dispose()

        'Function Return
        Return True

    Catch ex As Exception

        'Function Return
        Return False

    End Try
End Function
```

Any suggestions as to what the correct code it to call this sub?!

Comment: You might want to elaborate on "unable to call it" - is there an error message?  Can you show the code you try to invoke it with?  (BTW, it is not a `Sub`, its a `Function`)

Comment: Your function declaration needs to end with `As Boolean` so that other code knows to expect a Boolean value from it. I suspect that you have other errors in your code like that: if you use [Option Strict On](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zcd4xwzs.aspx) then Visual Studio will point them out for you. Correcting them may even may your code work. P.S. You may need `Public Shared Function SendEmail...` if you are not instantiating it.

Comment: @Plutonix the code I am using to call it is `SendEmail()`, however i get a `Arguemnt not specified for parameter 'EmailAsHTML of Public Function SendEmail.... '` on an Error Correction Options Box

Comment: Look at the signature you have for SendMail - it *requires* those 5 params to be specified.

Comment: I've been staring at this screen for far too long to miss something like that!! Thanks for your answer to something so stupid!!